# Android SDK Tools

Tags: android, android-studio

Where can I find information about all listed Android SDK Tools, what they mean and  (maybe) how to use.

[image]

Comment: I think you just need to google search them or search through android docs, to my knowledge there isn't much information in Android Studio just the option to install more components

Comment: Please check this out https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools

Answer (score 1):

The best place to visit is [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/) site.

**Android SDK Tools** is a component of the Android SDK. It includes the complete set of development and debugging tools for Android. It comes as a part of Android Studio. So if you install Android Studio, Android SDK tools will also get installed. You can also install it separately if you are using any other IDE like Eclipse for development.

Please refer the links below to get a better understanding of,

1. [Android SDK Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools) released so far.
2. [Android SDK Platform Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms)
3. [Android SDK Build Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools)
4. [Android Support Library Packages](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages)

Answer (score 0):

**Android SDK Platform-Tools is a component for the Android SDK.** It includes tools that interface with the Android platform, such as adb, fastboot, and systrace. These tools are required for Android app development. They're also needed if you want to unlock your device bootloader and flash it with a new system image.

Although some new features in these tools are available only for recent versions of Android, the tools are backward compatible, so you need only one version of the SDK Platform-Tools.

Check it:

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools

I hope It helps!

Comment: I'd like to know about: *Google Plays.. *Google USB *Google Web *CMAKE *NDK *GPU Debugger